# Querying a sub-collection in firestore using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am fairly new to cloud functions and I am trying to create a notifications feature in my app. The notifications are stored in a sub-collection. The error shown at the logs is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined at
>   Promise.all.then.result (/srv/index.js:29:41).

What could be the issue?

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require ('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Employee_Details/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}")
.onWrite((change , context) =>{

  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

  //console.log("User ID:" + user_id + "| Notification ID : " + notification_id);

  return admin.firestore().collection("Employee_Details").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {

    const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;

    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("Employee_Details").doc(from_user_id).get();
    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Employee_Details").doc(user_id).get();

  //  console.log("FROM_DAT:" + from_data + "TO_DATA:" + to_data);


    return Promise.all([from_data , to_data]).then(result => {


      const from_name = result[0].data().first_name;
      const to_name =  result[1].data().first_name;

      return console.log("FROM: "+ from_name + "TO:" + to_name);


    });


  });



});
```

[image: Firestore structure]

[image: Sub-collection]

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to retrieve a non-existent employee? If the screenshots you have attached belong to the values you are trying to retrieve, there's no document in `Employee_Details` with the id at `Employee_Details.Gh82W1.Notifications.KR0CN4.from`.

Comment: @Ajordat You are right, thank you. The from ID belongs to the system admin who isn't in the Employee_Details table. All this time I thought that there was a problem on how I was querying that Notification sub-collection. For the purpose of clarification did Firebase change the syntax on retrieving a field within a document in a sub-collection in firebase cloud functions using node.js. I am asking because the way I am retrieving, I am using an old syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screenshots you have attached belong to the values you are trying to retrieve, there's no document in `Employee_Details` with the id at `Employee_Details.Gh82W1.Notifications.KR0CN4.from`. This is why `result[0]` is undefined, because it couldn't retrieve anything.

Is there any reason why you think you are using *old* syntax? It seems correct to me. You are using the same methods as in the [sample code for nodejs](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/f8e1c353b83a5c1a9940ef9311c7ac291ecc36d4/firestore/main/index.js#L254-L273). The only change I would do is to avoid using `admin.firestore()` every time. Something like this:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const from_data = db.collection("Employee_Details").doc(from_user_id).get();
const to_data = db.collection("Employee_Details").doc(user_id).get();
```

But that's a personal preference.